# Cannot turn on/off offline folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

A Windows 7 laptop user has been using offline files/folders while overseas, and today, he no longer has the right-click menu option of "make available offline".

He still has read/write access to the folders in question.

How can we restore this menu option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by changing the user's AD group policy.  I didn't make the change myself, so I don't know the detail unfortunately.